# In Asp.Net 2.0 web site project and Assembly Reference?

Tags: asp.net, web

Where is the information about the Referenced Assembly kept in an Asp.Net 2.0 Web Site project. Since, there is no .csproj file here we don't know where to look for this. We are facing problems because of multiple version of log4Net being referenced and want to remove one of them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only information a website has is the fact that the DLL exists in the bin directory of the website.  When you add an external DLL to a project, that DLL is copied into the bin, and a .refresh file is added that provides Visual Studio with the path to the original DLL, so that it can refresh the DLL when it changes.

As far as I know, the assembly tag in web.config is only for GAC assemblies that are added to a project, not external DLLs.

As to your specific problem, if you have class libraries, it is possible that one of those references a different version of the DLL.  It is also possible that you have multiple websites and one of them has a .refresh file that is pointing to a different version of the DLL.

Answer (score -1):

In the web.config file under "assembly" tag

Comment: If I add an Assembly reference to the project will it copies the Assembly in the bin folder but nothing is added in the Web.Config.